# use a CountDownLatch multiple times

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

Is there any way to use a unique `CountDownLatch` multiple times?

I mean after creating an instance of `CountDownLatch` and set it's count value, after it reaches 0 by invoking `countDown()` method on that instance, we set a new count value and again start to count down on that instance or when a `CountDownLatch` reaches 0, it will set it's count value automatically to the value that we determine in it's constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

Use [`CyclicBarrier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html) instead, which supports [`reset`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html#reset()).

Comment: there isn't any way by using just countDownLatch?

Comment: No. You need to custom a reset method.  Here is a reset-able version. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6595835/resettable-countdownlatch