# What is different between CountDownLatch and Cyclic Barriers?

Tags: java

Well, I was going through the `Java concurrency in practice, by  Brian Goetz,` and found difficult to understand in different between `CountDownLatch` and `Cyclic Barriers`.

It's look like both are same except that cyclic barriers can be reused  ?

The books says that: 
`Latches are waiting for events, barriers are waiting for other threads` 
This statement seems to be very confusing. Not sure if this is a misquote by the authors or it has a real meaning. Functionally they appear to be same and it isn't difficult to rewrite a better version of CountDownLatch   which is re-usable with a method like reset().

Not sure of the practical life application of cyclic barriers over count down latches ?

Though looks similar to one of the questions already asked on this blog ( about latches and barriers ), but this questions strives to understand some other subtleties.

Comment: Sounds Like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168772/java-concurrency-countdown-latch-vs-cyclic-barrier?rq=1