# how to synchronize part of method on different threads

Tags: java, multithreading

Let us assume we have a method:

```
public class DoStuff implements Runnable {
    public void run()
    {
        A();
        B();
        C();
    }
}
```

Is there a simple way to create `n` threads that will run all A(), then all B(), then all C()?

I know that I can do something like:

```
    ExecutorService app = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadCount);

    //create A class and run A();

    app.shutdown();

    app.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
```

For A() then B() then C(), but I want something like the following:

```
public class DoStuff implements Runnable {
    public void run()
    {
        A();
        //wait all A to finish;
        B();
        //wait all B to finish;
        C();
    }
}
```

Using the same threads all the time.

Comment: Have a look at `CountDownLatch` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html

Comment: @Qwerky - A `CountDownLatch` cannot be *re-initialized*. Whereas a `CyclicBarrier` can be. So the OP will ahve to call `await()` after each method call to make the *current thread wait* and then initialize the `CyclicBarrier count` again and then call `await()` for `B` and so on

Comment: In addition to the actual answers to your question, please consider  SRP ( http://www.oodesign.com/single-responsibility-principle.html ) as well. A method should be doing **one** thing. Not two, three or n. Meaning: probably your threads should not be executing a run() with "A; B; C;" ... but run() with either "A", or "B", or "C".

Comment: @TheLostMind I think I would have two `CountDownLatch` instances, one inbetween A and B, and another in between B and C.

Comment: @Qwerky - That would work as well..:)

Comment: @Jägermeister, the sequence A(); B(); C(); might _be_ one thing when described at a higher level of abstraction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for CyclicBarrier

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168772/java-concurrency-countdown-latch-vs-cyclic-barrier

Answer (score -1):

you need to make A, B and C as threads and you need to join them.
Join A with B and B with C.

In this way you are making B thread to wait until A's job is done and C thread to wait until B's job is done.

Comment: A, B and C in this question are not threads but methods that are ran by all threads.

Comment: In a multithreaded environment, you can assure sequential execution of A,  B and C unless they are made individual threads and joined together...